# LightSwitch - template error in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I was exploring LightSwitch in VS 2012. I managed to created few sample app based on some online tutorials. When i try to open the VS today and create sample app again i got error.

Error
[image]
Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is there anything in your computer's Event Logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem, and this thread solution worked for me:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0d9963b7-6bed-42ce-a054-c8c5c998aef6/error-this-template-attempted-to-load-component-assembly

There is a response from Robert Schoen that points to a registry key that is causing this error. Changing the value of Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lsproj from "VisualStudio.Launcher.lsproj.10.0" to "VisualStudio.Launcher.lsproj.11.0" solves the issue, although seems it may be changed back by LS2011 setup, changing this registry key is much faster than repairing VS2012 installation.

Answer (score -1):

Have you imstalled any other programs on your machine?

You could try a repair of VS 2012.